# Multiple imputation: How many subjects per variable are needed?

Tags: r, sample-size, multiple-imputation, mice

I want to perform a multiple imputation via the mice package in R. My dataset looks as follows:

- 250 observations
- 60 variables
- variable type: numeric
- approximately 7-10% missings per variable
- multiple imputation method: predictive mean matching

Most of my variables are correlated with each other. Further, I have found some literature, which says that it is better/doesn't hurt to include more variables in the imputation model. Therefore I am planning to include all 60 variables of my dataset in my imputation model.

However, I am wondering if there can appear any problems, because I have only 250 observations in my dataset. Is there a rule of thumb how many observations per variable are needed for an adequate multiple imputation?